# Is there a way to choose the column for .writerow?

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape a site and save the data in a *csv* file that could be opened in Excel. I've managed to retrieve the information, but I have trouble transferring it to a *csv* document. When I open the document, the headers are there and in different columns, but the actual contents are in the same one, *name* first and *price* second.

I have tried putting `file.writerow([Name, Price])` at the end of the code, but, probably because I've used `span.find` for *name*, only the last name value is displayed. I figured `file.writerow` has to be in the loop to work, but I can't move the data to another column.

Here's the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

file = csv.writer(open('GPU.csv', 'w'))
file.writerow(['Name','Price'])

url = 'link'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')

for span in soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class':'details'}):
    name = span.find('a').string
    file.writerow([name])

for span in soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class':'price'}):
    price = span.findAll(text=True)
    file.writerow([price])
```

If there is nothing I can do with `file.writerow`, looping could be the issue. I have no experience with coding and would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `csv` module always only writes sequentially. However, you can gather the `name`s and `prices` up into separate lists up front, then use the `zip()` function to iterate over them in pairs, like so:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = "link"

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

names = []
prices = []

for span in soup.findAll("span", attrs={"class": "details"}):
    names.append(span.find("a").string)

for span in soup.findAll("span", attrs={"class": "price"}):
    prices.append(span.findAll(text=True))

file = csv.writer(open("GPU.csv", "w"))
file.writerow(["Name", "Price"])

for name, price in zip(names, prices):
    file.writerow([name, price])
```